# Powershell excel copy filtered data to new worksheet

Tags: excel, powershell, filter, copy

I have the following code to apply a formula and filter the results. It works fine. Next step I want to copy the filtered data to a new worksheet. How to do it?

```
$worksheet = $excel.Worksheets.Item(1)
$WorksheetRange = $workSheet.UsedRange
$RowCount = $WorksheetRange.Rows.Count 
$worksheet.range("G2:G$RowCount").formula = "=(SUM(E2-F2))" 
$rng = $excel.Range("G1").EntireColumn
$rng.select
$excel.selection.AutoFilter(7,"<=0")
$xlCellTypeVisible = 12
$cells = $worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Item(1).SpecialCells($xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Trying this too but it is not working:

```
$worksheet = $excel.Worksheets.Item(1)
$worksheetNew = $excel.Worksheets.Item(2)
#$worksheetNew = $excel.Workbooks.worksheets.add()
$xlCellTypeVisible = 12 
#$cells = $worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Item(1).SpecialCells($xlCellTypeVisible)
$worksheet.Range("A1:H100").SpecialCells($xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
$worksheetNew.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Trying this too but it is not working. Adding a new worksheet is also not working 
$worksheet = $excel.Worksheets.Item(1)

$worksheetNew = $excel.Worksheets.Item(2)

#$worksheetNew = $excel.Workbooks.worksheets.add()

 

$xlCellTypeVisible = 12

#$cells = $worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Item(1).SpecialCells($xlCellTypeVisible)

$worksheet.Range("A1:H100").SpecialCells($xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

$worksheetNew.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested this is how I solved the problem

```
$worksheet = $excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$worksheetNew = $excel.ActiveWorkbook.worksheets.add()
$worksheet.activate()
$xlCellTypeVisible = 12
$worksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeVisible).Copy()
$worksheetNew.activate()
$temp =$worksheetNew.Range("A1")
$worksheetNew.Paste($temp, $false)
```